# Empty request body when when using curl

Tags: apex, rest, apexrest

I have a rest service in salesforce which it has to receive different requests. When I test the service sending requests, if I use a REST Client I am able to get the requestbody properly but if I use curl to send the request, always I get an empty request body.

Where is the problem??

My code is so simply

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/web/*') //Endpoint
global class MRS_WS_FAMRS_Web {
@HttpPost
global static String doPost(){
    String reqBody;
    try{
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request; 
        //For debug only
        Blob reqBody2 = req.requestBody;
        System.debug('reqBody2: ' + reqBody2);
        System.debug('reqBody2size: ' + reqBody2.size());
        reqBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        System.debug('reqBody: ' + reqBody);
        if(req.requestBody.toString() != null){
            System.debug('REQUEST BODY -->: ' + req.requestBody.toString());
            MRS_FAMRS_MethodUtils.enviarMail(req.requestBody.toString(), 'Cuerpo request');
            return 'MRS_WS_FAMRS_Web --> DATA RECEIVED';
        }else return 'request body is null';
     }catch(Exception e){
            return 'ERROR';
     }
}
}
```

If I use a rest client I can get the data

[image]

But if I use curl I can't

[image]

I don't know if I am doing something wrong. Please help!!

Edit: To test with curl I have used [curl online](https://onlinecurl.com/), the curl command is:

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Authorization: OAuth XXXXX' -i 'https://cs108.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/web' --data '{"status":1,"msg":"","response":[{"id":"1","nombre":"","letra":"C"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Protector","letra":"P"},{"id":"3","nombre":"Estudiante","letra":"E"},{"id":"4","nombre":"Benefactor","letra":"B"}]}'
```

And the response I get is:

[image]

SOLVED: I have added the header Content-type: application/json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved adding the header Content-type: application/json. Now I am able to get the request body if I send the request via curl

Answer (score 1):

Check the HTTP response code that are being returned. It could be that you have an error in your curl request.

EDIT: pass your body content enclosed with double quotes instead of single quotes and escape the inner quotes in your JSON.

Comment: question edit with the curl command and the answer

Comment: @javier I edited your post, NEVER leave your auth token in there!

Comment: also, I wouldn't trust a third party site with that info, you should use a local curl.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks @POZ i solved the problem adding the header Content-type: application/json. And so many thanks for warning about the token, it was a copy paste code, I was desperated and I didn't realize about it. Thank you again

Comment: no worries, glad you solved it.